nav2 goal not moving
Using plugin gz: When using sim:: systems:: DiffDrive mode, the robot can move on its own by setting its position using nav2 goal in rviz, but with the use of the plugin gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2Control and Nav2 goal to set the position, the robot cannot move at all times. Using the keyboard in both ways can make the robot move. How should I solve this problem? thank you!
robot_spawn_launch.py
Partial code
Relay node to republish camera_info to /camera_info
relay_camera_info_node = Node(
    package='topic_tools',
    executable='relay',
    name='relay_camera_info',
    output='screen',
    arguments=['camera/camera_info', 'camera/image/camera_info'],
    parameters=[
        {'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')},
    ]
)



load_joint_state_controller = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
        'trobot_joint_state_broadcaster'],
    output='screen'
)

load_diff_drive_controller = ExecuteProcess(
    cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active','trobot_diff_drive_controller'], 
    output='screen')

reg_event_handler_joint_state_activate =RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=spawn_urdf_node,
            on_exit=[load_joint_state_controller],))     reg_event_handler_diff_drive_activate =RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=load_joint_state_controller,
            on_exit=[load_diff_drive_controller],))

nav2 launch
Partial code
nav2_bringup_dir = get_package_share_directory('nav2_bringup')
rviz_config_dir = os.path.join(
    nav2_bringup_dir, 'rviz', 'nav2_default_view.rviz')

use_sim_time = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration(
    'use_sim_time', default='true')
map_yaml_path = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration(
    'map', default=os.path.join(fishbot_navigation2_dir, 'maps', 'room.yaml'))
nav2_param_path = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration(
    'params_file', default=os.path.join(fishbot_navigation2_dir, 'config', 'nav2_params.yaml'))

return launch.LaunchDescription([

    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument('use_sim_time', default_value=use_sim_time,
                                         description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true'),
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument('map', default_value=map_yaml_path,
                                         description='Full path to map file to load'),
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument('params_file', default_value=nav2_param_path,
                                         description='Full path to param file to load'),

    launch.actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
            [nav2_bringup_dir, '/launch', '/bringup_launch.py']),
     
        launch_arguments={
            'map': map_yaml_path,
            'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
            'params_file': nav2_param_path}.items(),
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        arguments=['-d', rviz_config_dir],
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}],
        output='screen'),
])

